# Launching more than one container per instance on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a server written in Scala and deployed in Elastic Beanstalk. I'm writing a replacement in Node.js and I'm toying with the idea of deploying it using Docker on EB.

However, EB seems to launch one EC2 instance per container. There's also a [Multi-Container mode](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html), but that seems to be for different containers, doing different things. I get the sense that if I deploy multiple copies of my container that way, I'll have to load balance them myself.

The reason I want to use EB is to use all the extra bells and whistles like load balancing, easy scaling and monitoring.

Semi-related question: perhaps [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloud-container-management/) is more suited to my needs, but again, what about load balancing etc.?

Comment: Can you share more details on your usecase? If I understand correctly you you want to run multiple copies of the same application on the same instance. Is there a reason?

Comment: I believe one instance can take multiple servers with ease. That of course depends on the instance type, but I think it might be cost effective to do it that way.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to have more concurrency within the server per instance rather than spinning up multiple containers? Of course that would depend on the architecture of your application and benchmarking results.

Comment: The service is pretty concurrent, but I think it provides more granular control to be able to launch more than one container, when just the one isn't utilizing the entire instance. Although I'm starting to see what you're saying.